# How to open iOS App Store from website in a WebView wrapped app?

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

We have an old iOS app which used WebView to load our website at "m.blablabla.com" (basically, it was wrapping our mobile website).

It's really old. We don't even have build files for that anymore. It has been replaced by a new native app.

But we still have thousands of users who haven't upgraded (even though they can), probably because they turned off auto-update and don't check for updates.

So we added an html/css/javascript message to the mobile website saying "**We have a new app! This one will stop being supported soon. [ Update Now ]**"

Here I am, genius with no iOS WebView experience (and no environment to test this old app either). I linked the "Update Now" button to our app on the itunes websites, thinking -- it's a WebView, I'm sure the Apple device will figure out it needs to open the app store.

Nope!

Button **click does nothing**.

I'm actually not sure why it's not working -- not sure if the button click is not registering, or because the device doesn't know what to do with the link.

Any suggestions?

Is there perhaps a specific way to launch app store using JavaScript when this button is clicked...?

**Code sample:** HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="update()">Update Now</a>
```

**Code sample:** JavaScript

```
function update () {
    window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/blablabla/id123456789';
}
```

(Just extracted the relevant code. Implementation is slightly different. On our Android WebView app, it redirects user inside the WebView to the Google Play store app page [using the google play store url]. So the surrounding code is fine, we tested it by mocking the app in Google Chrome. But in the iOS app, just looks like the app doesn't know what to do with the url.)